# Convert array of arrays to json in Python

Tags: python, arrays, flask, sqlalchemy

I have an array of arrays which I get from a database query using *SQLAlchemy* and I want to do two things.

- I want to get the name of the columns (or something like *SELECT fullname AS "name n' surname" from table*).
- I want to convert the final product to a json array of objects, so that I can use it on the front-end.

I have searched several hours and couldn't find an answer that works for my case.

Here is the line of code querying the database and storing it in *results* variable:

```
results = session.query(categories.categoryname, products.pack, products.price, products.checkstate).join(products).all()
```

Here is the output of `print(results)`:

> [('chocolate', '3', 5, False), ('chocolate', '5', 7, False), ('chocolate', '10', 10, False), ('honey', '3', 5, False), ('honey', '5', 7, False), ('honey', '10', 10, False), ('candy', '3', 5, False), ('candy', '5', 7, False), ('candy', '10', 10, False)]

If I use `json.dump(results)` I get this:

> [["chocolate", "3", 5, false], ["chocolate", "5", 7, false], ["chocolate", "10", 10, false], ["honey", "3", 5, false], ["honey", "5", 7, false], ["honey", "10", 10, false], ["candy", "3", 5, false], ["candy", "5", 7, false], ["candy", "10", 10, false]]

Now to be more specific, what I'm trying to end up with is this:

> [{"type": "chocolate", "pack": "3", "price": 5, "checkstate": false}, ....etc... ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply loop through your list of tuples to create dictionaries, which then can be converted to a JSON. Something like this:

```
import json

data = [('chocolate', '3', 5, False), ('chocolate', '5', 7, False), ('chocolate', '10', 10, False), ('honey', '3', 5, False), ('honey', '5', 7, False), ('honey', '10', 10, False), ('candy', '3', 5, False), ('candy', '5', 7, False), ('candy', '10', 10, False)]

list = [{"pack": x[0], "pack": x[1], "price": x[2], "checkstate": x[3]} for x in data]

json.dumps(list)
```