# Writing multiple lists into JSON file

Tags: python, json

I'm able to store a single list into a json file to be used later. How would you store multiple lists into a json file. Let's say that I wanted to add the username to the file and the username + '@gmail.com" as another list into the same file. How would you access these two lists from the json file later?

```
import json
username = johnsmith91
storelist = []
storelist.append(username)
with open('username.json', 'a') as outfile:
    json.dump(storelist, outfile)
```

Comment: maybe an array of arrays?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert array of arrays to json in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52776092/convert-array-of-arrays-to-json-in-python)

Comment: You should probably be storing a list of dictionaries rather than multiple lists. E.g. `[{"username": "johnsmith91", "email": "johnsmith91@gmail.com"}, ...]`

Comment: you are right @barmar thanks.