# How can I append an array to json?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a json file I am reading the file with:

```
with open('/content/data.json', 'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        text = literal_eval(line)
        print(text)
```

```
{'id': 297162425, 'id_str': '297162425'}
{'id': 1257964204650192897, 'id_str': '1257964204650192897'}
...
...
...
```

I have predicted output in array format:
pred_ada_test = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1 ,1, 1, 1, 1 ,0]

How can I append the array to the json file like:

```
{'id': 297162425, 'id_str': '297162425','bot':1}
{'id': 1257964204650192897, 'id_str': '1257964204650192897','bot':1}
{'id': 934417886159896576, 'id_str': '934417886159896576','bot':0}
...
...
...
```

I tried to first convert the array to json:

```
list_to_json_array = json.dumps(pred_ada_test)
dict = {'bot':list_to_json_array}
```

then updated the json but got errors

It would be great if someone can help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: Try following this threat https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52776092/convert-array-of-arrays-to-json-in-python

Comment: can you please send more clear example

Comment: Try this one than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884840/adding-a-new-array-element-to-a-json-object

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('/content/data.json', 'r') as file:
    all_lines = file.readlines()
    line_idx = 0
    for line in all_lines:
        j = json.loads(line)
        j['bot'] = pred_ada_test[line_idx]
        all_lines[line_idx] = str(j)
        line_idx += 1


with open('/content/data.json', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(all_lines)
```

Comment: Got an error
JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: convert single quote (') to double quote (") after read from file

Comment: how can I do so?

Comment: str.replace(old_value, new_value)